# In sports, what is the difference between a coach and a trainer?

Tags: meaning

Recently I seen in my gym in basketball court "Rules for Coaches and Trainers..."
What is the difference between Coaches and Trainers in sport context? Why they specifically named separately in the rules?

here it's interesting topic regarding link between train and coach to transportation context [Are the dual transportation and learning meanings of both "coach" and "train" just a coincidence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286450/are-the-dual-transportation-and-learning-meanings-of-both-coach-and-train-ju/286451#286451)

Comment: Top result in Google: https://www.coachup.com/nation/articles/coach-vs-trainer-

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that one of the expectations of Stack Exchange is that you demonstrate some initial research efforts; for example, looking up *[trainer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trainer)* in MW returns the definition "a person who treats the ailments and minor injuries of the members of an athletic team" and for *[coach](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coach)* as *one who instructs or trains, especially : one who instructs players in the fundamentals of a sport and directs team strategy* which seems like a fairly clear distinction to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Broadly speaking, a ***coach*** is someone who is in charge of the entire team's preparation, while a ***trainer***'s job is to focus on individual athletes' conditioning.

Linguistically ... uh ... etymologically ... the two words come from two different sources, even though they mean, roughly, the same thing.

***Train***, a verb meaning *instruct*, *discipline*, or *teach* was first recorded in the 16th Century. It comes from the Old French *train*, which means "to pull, draw," which, in turn, comes from from the Vulgar Latin *traginare*.

***Coach*** comes from the Hungarian kocsi szekér, a wagon of Kocs, village in Hungary where coaches were first made. The habit of calling a teacher coach may have come from the idea that the instructor carries his pupils. The origin of the term is traced to 19th Century Oxford slang.

Comment: And what about "manager"? What Germans call trainer is usually manager in English. I always found that interesting.

Comment: Also, a coach is the head representative of a team on the field/court, whereas a trainer is not.  A trainer might not even be present during a game because his work is usually pre-game, or leading up to the game.

Answer (score 2):

If this is in America, then the difference is that a "Coach" is the person responsible for the on-field training, tactics, technique, management, games, etc. A "Trainer", in America, is an "Athletic Trainer", who is responsible for the health and safety of the players, sort of like a Physio in Professional football in Europe.